# Temperature of copper block inside a metal container

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, thermal-radiation

I have one cylindrical metal container : ~20 cm in length; ~15 cm in diameter.
I have kept one small copper block inside this container. Copper block is thermally
insulated from all other components inside the metal container.
Container is air-tight. Room temperature is 25 C. When I measured temperature of the copper block (using a PT100 sensor which is glued to copper block), it was 31 C.

How is this possible? Temperature of copper block must be same as room temperature, isn't it?

Edit: PT100 sensor is calibrated correctly. Copper block was inside cylindrical container for one month. No radioactive material, no chemical reactions. Copper block is not in contact with cylinder. Is this due to some extra resistance in the path somewhere ?

Comment: Could you give us more detail. Is the device electrical or does it perhaps contains radioactive materials or something(s) undergoing a chemical reaction? How long has it been sitting in the room? Is there the chance of direct sunlight falling on the box some time recently (also, is it near a radiator)? Did you calibrate the sensing-device? Is the block in contact with the cylinder?

Comment: Please see Edit.

Comment: Is the copper block levitated within the container?

Comment: What is the temperature of the container and of the air inside?

Comment: @ChetMiller: No. Copper block is mounted on something and is thermally isolated from other components inside.

Comment: @nasu: Temperature of container and of air inside it is same as that of room temperature : ~25 C.

Comment: Perhaps you've a circuit diagram for us to see if there's something strange about the sensor's behaviour - there's a possibility it might be better suited to our electronics stack: [electronics.se].